# Depending of drag and drop operation from anchor position in unreal engine 4

Tags: drag-and-drop, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have the problem with Drag-and-Drop Operation for UI elements:
i have created a test object to drag: [DragTestObject_BP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLj3I.png) and  have override the functions:
[OnMouseBottonDown Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hZRQ.png) and [OnDragDetected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1rGO.png).
Recepient will be [HUD_BP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCflj.png) with overridden is [OnDrop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAoh6.png) function.

The problem is, that first drag-and-drop operation is functioning without problem only, if the anchor for drag object is set for upper left corner. Otherwise the drag object has some wired offset.

**Position on start:**

[image]

**Drag object jumped by first mouse click on it**

[image]

Comment: Isn't it better to use an Interface with DragStart and DragEnd functions that set the location as 2D coordinates directly in the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but youll want to put the widget you're clicking to drag ("DragTestObject_BP") inside of another widget.

It's probably a good idea to remove any canvas panel in "DragTestObject_BP" as well.

This will make the origin of "DragTestObject_BP" where it is located visually, instead of using the location of the canvas panel which is the issue you seem to have run into.